# How Oracle is related with GIS (Professional wise)

Tags: oracle-dbms, career, database

I am GIS B.Tech Graduate. In the aiming of becoming GIS Developer .I temporairly changed my profession from GIS Analyst to Software Engineer. But what I got in this software company is oracle (not .net or Python). I want know with gaining oracle experience how Can I comeback To GIS Domain any suggestions?

Comment: So, you want to know how Oracle DBMS can be used with various GIS software?

Comment: Ya definately yes by gaining oracle experience what are the positions i am eligible for applying in our GIS field?

Answer (score 6):

Oracle DBMS is is capable of storing spatial data either through custom formats (like Esri) or native ([Oracle Spatial](http://docs.oracle.com/html/A88805_01/sdo_intr.htm)). This means it is worth learning for **GIS Analyst** because you will be able to interact with the DBMS either by using SQL/PLSQL/[spatial SQL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_operat.htm) (for analysis and data retrieval, and you can do a lot with those spatial functions without using any desktop GIS interface).

As a **GIS Database Administrator/GIS DBA**, you will be able to administer the database (both database per se but also geospatial bits which involves spatial indices, multiuser editing, and geodata replication workflows). Oracle is used widely within multiple organizations who use Esri software together with ArcSDE to enable storing ArcGIS native enterprise geodatabase within Oracle database.

Natually, by learning Oracle you master SQL which can be used for any other SQL RDBMS. I find it especially useful to master spatial functions to be able to answer geographical questions with SQL, worth learning, too. A lot of those spatial functions are similar to PostGIS functions (and PostGIS is used very widely in GIS industry), so it will be a less steep learning curve to master PostGIS after getting savvy with Oracle.

You might be surprised, but there are [routing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_route_server.htm) and [geocoding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_geocode_concepts.htm) engines built into Oracle, too. So, a lot of **GIS consultancy** / GIS Analyst jobs are opened to those who have skills with that.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there are two ways. The most obvious is that Oracle has an Oracle Spatial module with lot's of GIS functionnalities. The second is that Oracle, as a RDBMS, is also used as a third party software for the table storage and analysis.

The experience you get by managing an RDBMS like Oracle should thus be easy to valorize for a GIS job.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up the top answer, a lot of online company's use Oracle real time scheduling systems (formerly Sidewinder) to organise and route their deliveries, (which uses the oracle spatial routing functionality). They are usually looking for GIS analysts to keep the underlying maps up to date.